# Word choice - What's the phrase to describe the idea that relative positions in society are meaningless?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to describe the idea that relative positions in society are meaningless.

So far I've come up with counterculturalism, societal positional nihilism, a 'beatnik'.

I'm sure there is something more concise.

Comment: What's wrong with [egalitarianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egalitarianism)?

Comment: Yes, it's `egalitarianism` and it's one of the core concepts from Enlightenment philosophy behind the founding of the US, so I don't think the terms you've come up with quite fit.  Unless Thomas Jefferson and his ilk are beatniks.  Hmm, Would that make George Washington Dobie Gillis?

Comment: When you say "meaningless" what exactly are you trying to convey?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"egalitarian" should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could also be looking for a [classless society](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_society), i.e. one where there are no distinctions of relative position.